# AngularJS: array[ {{value}} ] causes a parse error that I want to ignore

Tags: javascript, angularjs, parsing, angular-ngmodel, angularjs-ng-init

I have a selection list that I get from the controller, written like this:

```
<select class="input form-control"
    id="animationTime"
    ng-options="item as item.label for item in aniCon.timeOptions track by item.id"
    ng-model="aniCon.popupTime"
    ng-init="aniCon.popupTime = aniCon.timeOptions[{{aniCon.popupTime.id}}]">
</select>
```

This causes a parse error here: aniCon.timeOptions[**{...**, a value is expected not {{..

The thing is that this value `{{aniCon.popupTime.id}}` is seen as 3 when the page loads and then the html is correct: `aniCon.popupTime = aniCon.timeOptions[3]`

So I want to ignore this parse error somehow.

Comment: Generally, you should be initializing values in your controller, then you wouldn't have to worry about parsing through ng-init.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the brackets. For Angular directives, there is no need of using expressions

```
ng-init="aniCon.popupTime = aniCon.timeOptions[aniCon.popupTime.id]">
```

As @Patrick has said in comment, you should move the code of initialisation to the controller.

```
$scope.aniCon = {};
// Get the object values here
$scope.aniCon.popupTime = $scope.aniCon.timeOptions[$scope.aniCon.popupTime.id];
```